# Creating a Python Tkinter Executable. Issue is when running the program after creating the executable, the program can't find dependencies

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, pyinstaller, python-venv

This is a bit of a loaded question but I will set it up in order. I'm sure the answer is really simple and that I just wasn't aware about certain things...

1st: I have 2 python files. One is named `main.py` which is the program UI. The second is the program that the main.py program runs. It does this by grabing the python file from a specific directory.

2nd: I did `pip install pyinstaller` which is what I used to create the executable for main.py

3rd: Once everything is in the folder with the executable UI app, and I run the executable, I have the option to start and stop. When I press Start on the UI, it is supposed to run the program that it is connected to the start button.

The primary issue is that when I do press run, behind the UI exe window, there is a terminal, that displays `dependency_name not found` and it basically sits there. The dependencies are in a venv folder. The program the UI is for imports those. In the IDE, this works perfectly. The second it becomes standalone, it no longer can find those dependencies.

Both Python files, the exe, the venv folder (dependencies inside), and some other icons and images are all in one project folder that ideally should work alone with the exe for main.py inside.

Does anyone have an idea of what I might be doing wrong or maybe a step I missed?

Comment: There are a few fixes to this, start of by using terminal on the venv u created, then say pyinstaller code there and check and you will have to copy the exe to the project directory

Comment: @CoolCloud basically, you are saying to make the exe file inside of the venv file. What do I do with the program the UI is supposed to run... The issue is with the program the UI runs and how it doesn't find the dependencies when the entire project is standalone.

Comment: You will have to edit the spec file in that sense, to include dependencies such as images.

Comment: @CoolCloud the images are fine. Its dependencies like apis and other packages. Do you think I could do a. --addfile thing for Py installer or is that not an option. I would add my dependencies.